# How do I change the build folders in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm getting an error in a VS2010 DB project that indicates I have too many charachters in my build path.

How can I change my default build path for all project types?

Something like

```
c:\build\$(projectname)\......
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
I've moved my project to the root of the C: drive and I still get the error with my DB project. I get this error when I try to right click the project and select properties

**An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close the window and try again.
    Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "obj\Debug|Any CPU\TASS.DB.dbschema". Illegal characters in path.  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets**

Comment: I've uninstalled VS2010 and removed all of my extensions. the problem is now resolved. I think on of the extension i used caused the issue and I will try to find out which one and post back here

Comment: You did not understand the error message. The problem is not that "I have too many charachters in my build path". The problem is one invalid character in the path "obj\Debug|Any CPU\TASS.DB.dbschema", which obviously is the pipe character.

Comment: @Elmue Hah, yes indeed the problem was clearly the pipe character. In fact it was so clear that this information was in my original answer from over five years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out to me here is that your platform and configuration are being fused together to form "Debug|Any CPU" and a string is being made from that--the pipe is the character it's referencing there when it says there are illegal characters. I'm not sure how much your database project really differs with respect to debug/release and for architecture, but you may not even need to include them in the path.

Since you can't open the project property pages, you'll need to edit the msbuild directly by unloading it and selecting "Edit..." from the context menu (sorry if you know this already).

From there, assuming you're realling running up on the windows path length ceiling, you could use some msbuild trickery to maximize your headroom in there. Specifically, doing something similar to what you suggest: use the C:\ drive wherever possible.

To do this, look inside the PropertyGroups with the conditions for your Configuration & Platform configurations, and inside them replace the OutputPath and IntermediateOutputPath properties so that they're as short as possible, for example:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>$(SystemDrive)\D\A</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(SystemDrive)\o\D\A</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

- This saves some valuable characters in that instead of "Debug" you're using "D", "A" for "AnyCPU" and "o" for "obj".
- Probably most importantly you're using C:\o\ for the intermediate build directory instead of C:\whatever-the-whole-path-is-to-your-project-file\obj. As well, this property isn't configurable from the property pages, from what I recall.
- Some added flexibility there using SystemDrive instead of a hard-coded C:, not that I would really expect it to be different.

Finally, concerning your property pages load problem, I don't know how the Debug|AnyCPU got in your path (I don't know of any properties that store the concatenated flavor like that), but you should be able to pick it out pretty easily once you open up the file. Hopefully it's similar to load errors in something like the winforms designer where you change one line and suddenly the whole thing works again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for this but unfortunately it made no difference. i believe its something to do with one of my extensions. I'm going to test this and I'll edit my posit if I identify the problem. I appreciate your post. Well written and easy to follow :)

Comment: Thanks for the critique! Sorry this didn't get it done for you. I guess it must be something screwy with the database project files. I'd be happy to look over yours if there's no IP-oriented risks involved. I'm quickly becoming an msbuild junkie ;)

Comment: Thanks Bwerks. I think I found the problem extension. A set "tangible" extension I downloaded for T4 editing... not really sure why they would cause this, but I no longer need them so I wont be re-installing. your post didn't fixx my problem, but it did allow me to change build folders - so correct answer to my first Q! :)

Comment: Much obliged! Happy I could help with that much at least.

Comment: This answer is wrong. There are not "too many charachters in my build path" as 'littlechris' wrote. The error message says clearly that there is an invalid character in the path. So shortening the path can not be a solution.

Comment: @Elmue I'm going to assume you just didn't read the first paragraph of my answer, the first sentence of which points out the pipe character as the illegal character.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to set a default build path for all projects, only the standard Debug/Release folders within the project itself. The only suggestion I would have is to simply move the project folder to location with a shorter path.

EDIT: As per the new edit, have a look here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594333/database-project-template-files-corrupt

Comment: Thanks djfrear. i've tried this, but still get the same error in my DB project. I've edited my question above

Comment: Same as for all the others: You did not understand the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I updated a project from VS 2005 to VS 2010 and got the same error message. 
"***The item metadata "%(Filename)" cannot be applied to the path "obj\Debug|x86\Debug\DemoCSharp.pdb". Illegal characters in path.***" The problem is that Visual Studio 2010 fails in converting the csproj file to the new format, but it does not tell us where exactly the error is.

In my VS 2005 csproj file there is the following XML code:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">Debug|x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{05F88317-0CA7-4FE5-8520-35422402941A}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>DemoCSharp</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>DemoCSharp</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>..\output32\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>..\output32\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>..\output64\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' ">
    <OutputPath>..\output64\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Visual Studio does NOT tell us which line produces the problem. But I found it by "try and error".

The cause of the error message is clearly a **bug in the Visual Studio conversion wizard** because VS 2005 has no problem loading this csproj file while VS 2010 fails to convert it.

So you have to manually edit and fix this file and then load it anew in VS2010.

In my case the line that triggers the bug is the 3. line with `<Platform Condition`. The bug is that VS tries to take the **value**  ("Debug|x86") of this platform condition XML node and embed it into a path on disk (like "...\obj\Debug|x86\..."). But as **pipe characters are illegal in paths**, it later complains and aborts the conversion.

So how to solve the problem ?

I simply replaced the third line

```
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">Debug|x86</Platform>
```

with

```
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">Debug</Platform>
```

which eliminates the pipe character and the project converted without errors.

**NOTE:** It is also possible to completely delete this line.

**ATTENTION:**
It is possible that in YOUR case the same error messages needs another fix than in my case. Please study the csproj file and look for the pipe characters, then find out with try and error how to modify it. This error can even appear in other conditions than converting a project.

But what they all have in common is that this is a Visual Studio bug (or in case of 'littlechris' a software extension bug) that tries to embed a pipe character into the path.

```
XML node: "Debug|x86" -> path "...\obj\Debug|x86\..."
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this messeage because the absolute path of one of the files in my project exceeded 260 characters. Once I reduced the path length, I was able to build the project.